# Slight different solutions to shortest path

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, shortest-path

[image: This is from the book Algorithm Design]

[image: This is from the book Algorithms]

I first read this OPT formula from the book Algorithm Design(the first pic), I understand this very well I think, whether use i-1 edges or i edges leading to different `OPT(i-1,v)` or `OPT(i-1,w)+Cvw`.

However, when I read the same problem from the book Algorithms (the second pic starting from "In dynamic programming..."), I am confused because it eliminates the `OPT(i-1,v)`, which means delete the condition that path `P` uses at most `i-1` edges, and just using `OPT(i-1,w)+Cvw`. I was just wondering why this formula is still OK? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the distinction is in what the DP values mean. In the first case, the value means "the best path to v using *at most* i edges," and in the second the value means "the best path to v using *exactly* i edges." Given the second of these you can directly read off the answer by looking at the final DP value, whileas in the second you'd have to look at dp(v, 0), dp(v, 1), dp(v, 2), ... dp(v, n - 1).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you explain more about this sentence "Given the second of these you ... you'd have to look at dp(v, 0), dp(v, 1), dp(v, 2), ... dp(v, n - 1)." I do not quite understand what this means partly because English is my second language. Thx!

Comment: Sure! Using the first algorithm, OPT(v, n) is the length of the shortest path from u to v. Using the second, min{dist(v,0), dist(v,1), dist(v,2),...dist(v,n)} is the length of the shortest path from u to v.

Comment: So what you mean is using the second, there are two steps. First step, using dist(i,v) = min{dist(u,i-1)+l(u,v)}. Second step, using min(dist(i,v)). right?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it!